# how to pass a function parameter in Java 8 in stream groupby

Tags: java, java-stream

I am using stream group by like this in Java 8:

```
 reportProfitResult = reportProfits.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ReportProfitAnalysis::getStatisticTime));
```

Now I want to pass the group by field as a parameter in outer founction like this:

```
private void MapResult(E groupByField) {   
    reportProfitResult = reportProfits.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(groupByField));

}
```

what should I do to make it work as expect ? I have followed tips but still encount this problem:

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you want. `Collectors.groupingBy` (with a single parameter) returns a `Map<GroupType,List<StreamElementType>>`. How do you intend to get a `List<ReportProfitFormattedResponse>` from that `Map`? And what's `E groupByField`?

Comment: I have changed my code, the return is not important, I want to pass the group by condition by parameter. @Eran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-).

You need a `Function<? super T,? extends K> classifier` as the type, or something more specific depending on how your `ReportProfitAnalysis` and `reportProfitResult` look.

For example:

```
private void MapResult(Function<? super ReportProfitAnalysis, ?> func) {   
    reportProfitResult = reportProfits.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(func));
}
```

You can pass the grouping function

```
Function<? super ReportProfitAnalysis, ?> func = ReportProfitAnalysis::getStatisticTime;
```

Note that the `reportProfitResult` here would be defined as `Map<?, List<ReportProfitAnalysis>> reportProfitResult`

Answer (score 2):

In that case, the type of `groupByField` should be `Function<ReportProfitAnalysis, ? extends K>`, where `K` is a generic type parameter (assuming your `Stream` is a `Stream<ReportProfitAnalysis>`).

```
private <K> void MapResult(Function<ReportProfitAnalysis, ? extends K> groupByField) 
{   
    reportProfitResult = reportProfits.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(groupByField));
}
```

And you can call it, for example, with:

```
MapResult(ReportProfitAnalysis::getStatisticTime);
```

Comment: Seems it work ,but still have a little problem I do not know how to do. @Eran

Comment: I changed the return define and works. @Eran